# html2pdf generates a blank page

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2pdf

I have 46 html tables on the page and I want to generate a pdf with all those tables each on a separate page via html2pdf. But I get pdf file with only blank pages. This is my function

```
function generatePDF() {
                window.devicePixelRatio = 5;
                var opt = {
                    margin: 0.5,
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
                    pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all' },
                    html2canvas: { scale: 10 },
                    html2canvas: { dpi: 300 },
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait', precision: '12' }
                };
                var allTables = document.getElementsByClassName('table');
                for (var i = 0; i < allTables.length; i++) {
                    var tbID = allTables[i].id;
                    var element = document.getElementById(tbID);
                    element.classList.add('tableNoBorders');
                    allHtml += allTables[i].outerHTML;
                }
                html2pdf().set(opt).from(allHtml).save();
            }
```

I understand that it's happening because the element's too large and I could also decrease the scale or devicePixelRatio but the quality of pdf is really important and I don't want to do that.

Is there any way I can create pages one by one and merge them together at the end? I found a way to do that via jsPDF but I don't know how to add the options like scale, dpi and so on.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes. First, create a new jsPDF object with the desired options. Then, loop through each element that you want to add to the PDF and add it to a new page using the `addPage` method. Finally, save the PDF using the `save`.

Comment: That would be an ideal solution. However, I could not figure out how to add opt to jsPDF object. Is that possible?